Non-NA values being replaced as NA during Excel File Import into R
I have an excel file which I have imported into R using read_excel. The excel file contains about 8000+ records with 58 columns. There are many cells with NA values. Across the different variables, they may be entered as "n/a", "N/A", "n/A", "N/a","na","NA", "n a","(blank)".
When I'm importing the file, I use this code:
read_excel("path", col_names = TRUE, na = c("n/a", "N/A", "n/A", "N/a","na","NA", "n a",""))

In one column, I have records with this value NR, which stands for No Record and is not the same thing as NA.
When I run the read_excel code above, the NR becomes NA. If I take out the na = c("n/a", "N/A", "n/A", "N/a","na","NA", "n a","") section, the NR is imported as it should. How do I get R to recognize that NR is not the same thing? As a side note, I cannot change the NR notation to something else.

Cannot replicate this issue. And it is not clear why you cannot change the NR values, because you can simply change them back if NR is causing an issue. For instance, in Excel, use Replace All to change all NRs to a value unique in your file e.g. XYZ. Then, load your Excel file, and use something like  df <- df |> dplyr::mutate_all(~replace(., . ==  "XYZ", "NR")) to see if that resolves your issue.

@LTyrone Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, I can't change NR to something else as the NR notation is used by others in their own processes. However, based your suggestion, I did go back to make a copy of the spreadsheet and changed the NR there. The import issue still remains. When I checked it using unique(), it just shows 1, 0 and NA when it should be 1, 0, NA, NR.

What happens when you run class() on the column that is supposed to contain NR? I suspect since you are not specifying col_types in readxl::read_excel(), the default behavior, guess, thinks that the column is supposed to contain only numeric data, and therefore interprets NR as NA.

It's a bit of a clumsy solution, but given the NR values are only for one column, could you convert all the incorrectly converted NA values in that specific column back to NR once you've read in the data? I guess this assumes the column does not also have NA values.

@cristian-vargas your comment is bang on. It was indeed the col_types that was the issue!

You can try something like this to fix the problem :
### Packages
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

### Load your data with all columns typed to character
### which should preserved the NR value. Blank cells will be automatically converted to NA
NA_ <- read_excel("C:/Users/your_name/Downloads/NA.xlsx",
                  col_names = TRUE,
                  col_types ='text')

NA_ dataframe :
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  Prenom Nom     Values Ville       Record
  <chr>  <chr>   <chr>  <chr>       <chr> 
1 Jean   N/a     1      Paris       1     
2 n/a    Dupond  2      NA          3     
3 N/A    na      NA     Montpellier 4     
4 Marc   Spencer n a    NA          NR  

Time to transform all forms of n/a,N/A,... to real NA :
### Replace NA values with real NA using a regex
### Change afterwards the type of one or more columns if needed
NA_ %>% mutate(across(everything(),~str_replace(.x,"(?i)\\b(n\\s*\\/?\\s*a)\\b",NA_character_)),
               Values=as.numeric(Values))

Output :
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  Prenom Nom     Values Ville       Record
  <chr>  <chr>    <dbl> <chr>       <chr> 
1 Jean   NA           1 Paris       1     
2 NA     Dupond       2 NA          3     
3 NA     NA          NA Montpellier 4     
4 Marc   Spencer     NA NA          NR  


thank you for the solution! Your suggestion of setting the col_types to text did the trick. I modified your solution slightly in that I kept my original na = c(...) in the read_excel. In the class for the column, I can now see the values that I want 1, 0, NA, NR. I can confirm that both your suggestion and my modification works though!
